# How can create trigger in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have two tables `employee` and `emp_pf`. I want to created trigger to Insert employee PF according to 10% of employee salary and also INSERT `emp_id` in `emp_pf` table. But here problem is I can not write down dynamic code in trigger to Insert `emp_id` and `pf`.

**TRIGGER**

```
CREATE TRIGGER `pf_count` AFTER INSERT ON `employee`
  FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO emp_pf (emp_id,pf) values(1,100)
```

My question is how to write trigger code to dynamically insert `emp_id` and calculate 10% of salary for `pf`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/966c5/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution to insert record in `emp_pf` table when new Record Inserted in `employee` table, Using `NEW` keyword.

**TRIGGER Query**

```
CREATE TRIGGER `pf_count` AFTER INSERT ON `employee`
 FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO emp_pf (emp_id,pf) values(NEW.id,NEW.salary*0.10);
```

In trigger it's count 10% of salary for PF and Insert record in `emp_pf` table.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69b89/1)